# Storing safe HTML

Tags: html, mysql, ruby, escaping

I want to download a list of web addresses, and store them in database (Mysql). How can I make safe htmls? What can I use instead of

```
safe_html = make_safe_it(html) # HERE
```

in the code below?

```
require 'mysql2'
require 'open-uri'

HOST = "..."
USER = "..."
PASS = "..."

@client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host=> HOST,:username=>USER,:password => PASS)
@client.query "USE db_test"
@client.query("SELECT id,url from pages").each{ |row|
   html = open(row["url"]).read
   safe_html = make_safe_it(html) # HERE
   @client.query("UPDATE pages SET html = #{safe_html} where id = #{row["id"]} ")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested in https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2 use `escaped = client.escape("gi'thu\"bbe\0r's")`